# Clearing (and Resetting) Material Select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I know there's a few questions already on this, but none of the answers seem to work.

I have a series of Angular selects (`mat-select`). The options chosen in one `mat-select` effect the options available in subsequent `mat-select` instances. For instance, if the first `mat-select` allowed you to choose `fruit` or `vegetable`, the second `mat-select` might have `apple` and `orange` if you chose `fruit` or `cucumber` and `potato` if you chose `vegetable`.

The problem is that if you then go back and change your `fruit`/`vegetable` selection, I need to clear the second `mat-select` (otherwise, it just displays the new item that has the same selected index).

I've tried using `patchValue` to set the value of the control to null. I've tried calling `reset` on the control. None of the options I've found seem to work.

Are there any examples of this working to which I can refer?

Comment: As I understand, you want to clear the second select when you change the parent one. Could be something like this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/WEH5bNkXZS110VNZDUmQ?p=preview) your desired behavior? I think that you have to clean the model of second mat-select when the first one model's changes, that's alll. I will post a more detailed answer if I'm right... If not, update the plunker and use it for your question :)

Comment: @The.Bear Sorry for not including more specifics. I'm doing this inside a `mat-stepper`, with different forms for each step. Since it's inside a `fromGroup`, each control has a `formControlName`, which IIRC means I can't utilize `ngModel` binding. That __seems__ to be what's screwing me up here. I can access the select via the `formControlName`, but I can't seem to reset the value that way. I'll try to modify the plnkr to more accurately reflect the situation, but if you know of a way to include an `ngModel` binding inside the `form`, that would fix the problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get it working. I'm not sure why it works now and didn't previously, but I've clearly changed something from my initial attempts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer turned out to be that I needed to use the `[(ngModel)]` binding on each `mat-select` **and** assign a `formControlName` to each `mat-select` in order to get it to work within a `formGroup`.